# Taking data argument in a created NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How can I send `data argument` in an already created `NSString`. I have an `NSDictionary`:

```
NSArray *objectsArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"item id %i",@"random id %i",nil];
NSArray *keysArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"item",@"random",nil];
NSDictionary *dataDictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:objectsArray forKeys:keysArray];
```

Somewhere down the code I ask for the object in the NSDictionary

```
NSString *counterString=[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"random"];
```

How Can I now pass `data argument` into this `retrieved NSString`? 
so my final string looks like

> random id 67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:counterString, digit];
```

If you also need to store it in your dictionary add

```
dataDictionary[@"random"] = finalString;
```

Comment: But my incoming data is in instance variable "int digit=67;"

Comment: Not a problem - I have updated the answer. Please do not forget to accept the answer if your issue is solved!

Comment: My bad, I had been using this exact code but the problem was with some other data written into the NSDictionary that making it give me a 'exc_bad_access code=2' error. Thanks for prompt help anyways :)

Comment: Man it might seem to you that way but honestly I thought there was something wrong with my code but doing research later about the above error I realised it was a mem allocation issue. Thanks a ton for your help to me and anyone who comes to this page.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *objectsArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"item id %i",@"random id %i",nil];
NSArray *keysArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"item",@"random",nil];
NSDictionary *dataDictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:objectsArray forKeys:keysArray];

NSString *counterString=[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"random"];

NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:counterString, 67];

dataDictionary[@"random"] = final;
```

Comment: It seems that you just copied my answer.

Comment: @Avt Please have a look on your and my answer.